# Frame a text in a tabularx and item environment

Tags: tabularx

In my document, I have text displayed next to an image in a environment `\tabularx` : in this text there is also an environment `\itemize`

I would like to be able to frame all the text next to the image but my tests are not working and are returning errors.

Can anyone help me ?

Thank you in advance.

````
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[european, RPvoltages, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newenvironment{manip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}{\end{itemize}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{moresize}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 


\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}


\begin{document}
\section{Lois de l'électricité}
 \subsection{Loi des mailles ou loi d'additivité des tensions}
\begin{center}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} cX @{}}
\includegraphics[width=56mm, valign=c]{example-image}
    & \textbf{Manip} :
\begin{manip}
\item faire le montage
\item tester s'il marche
\item attendre !
\end{manip}
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easier solutions would be to use the lines of the table (not the ones provided by `booktabs`!). The width is then defined by the width of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newenvironment{manip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
    \section{Lois de l'électricité}
    \subsection{Loi des mailles ou loi d'additivité des tensions}
    \begin{center}
        \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} c|X @{}|}
            \cline{2-2}
            \includegraphics[width=56mm, valign=c]{example-image}
            & \textbf{Manip} :
            \begin{manip}
                \item faire le montage
                \item tester s'il marche
                \item attendre !
            \end{manip}\\ \cline{2-2}
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not want the text to touch the frame, a simple workaround is an empty column with a defined space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newenvironment{manip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}{\end{itemize}}
\begin{document}
    \section{Lois de l'électricité}
    \subsection{Loi des mailles ou loi d'additivité des tensions}
    \begin{center}
        \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} c|X p{.5cm} @{}|}
            \cline{2-3}
            \includegraphics[width=56mm, valign=c]{example-image}
            &
                \textbf{Manip} :
            \begin{manip}
                \item faire le montage faire le montagefaire le montagefaire le montagefaire le montagefaire le montagefaire le montage
                \item tester s'il marche
                \item attendre !
            \end{manip}&\\ \cline{2-3}
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unrelated: You are using `libertine` and `lmodern`. The former will have no effect on your font, because you load another font (`lmodern`) at a later point.

Comment: I had tried this method but I was not positioning ```\cline``` correctly! When the text is too long on a single line, it ends up stuck to the frame: can we define an invisible border to space?

Comment: thank you in any case for your wise advice! @Markus G.

Comment: I'm not sure, I understood what the problem is, but I tried adding a third column (see above)

Comment: it is effective in any case thank you