# Another text frame containing a tabularx environment

Tags: tabularx

This question follows a previous request : [previous request](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599399/frame-a-text-in-a-tabularx-and-item-environment/599408?noredirect=1#comment1502601_599408)

Later in my document, I have some text that contains a `tabularx` environment. As this table does not take up all the space of the text that I want to frame, the solution proposed to my previous request does not work : I get errors

Can you help me ?

Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\newenvironment{manip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\itemmanip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}


\begin{document}
    \section{Spectre électrique}
    \subsection{Numérisation d'un signal}
    
%Text to frame    
\paragraph{Manipulation 1 : programme numerisation.ino}
\begin{manip}
    \item \'{A} l’aide d’un oscilloscope, on règle un GBF de manière à obtenir une sinusoïde de fréquence $f = \SI{1}{\hertz}$ tout le temps positive dont la tension crête à crête est de $\SI{4}{\volt}$ sans dépasser une valeur maximale de $\SI{5}{\V}$ ;
    \item A l’aide de 2 pinces croco, on relie la carte Arduino (bornes A0 et GND) au GBF ;
    \item Ouvrir le moniteur série et saisir les données demandées selon les valeurs du tableau ci-dessous :
    \end{manip}
    \smallbreak
    \begin{tabularx}{0.7\linewidth}{@{}lYYYYYYY@{}}
        \toprule
        $f_{echantillonnage} (\si{\hertz}$)  & 100 & 50 & 20 & 10 & 5 & 2 & 1 \\ \midrule
        nombre de bit & \multicolumn{7}{c}{10} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your error is unrelated to the table. You have `! LaTeX Error: \begin{itemize} on input line 31 ended by \end{document}.` as you never end the list;

Comment: as you see here, it is bad style to hide the environment syntax with commands such as `\newcommand{\itemmanip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}`  it makes it easy to miss the end environment.

Comment: it's a bad copy paste because in my document I have the ```\end{itemize}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any boxed environment, the fact that it contains a table shouldn't really affect anything. I just use a basic `\fbox` here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\newenvironment{manip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\itemmanip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}


\begin{document}
    \section{Spectre électrique}
    \subsection{Numérisation d'un signal}
    
\noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}    
\paragraph{Manipulation 1 : programme numerisation.ino}
\begin{manip}
    \item \'{A} l’aide d’un oscilloscope, on règle un GBF de manière à obtenir une sinusoïde de fréquence $f = \SI{1}{\hertz}$ tout le temps positive dont la tension crête à crête est de $\SI{4}{\volt}$ sans dépasser une valeur maximale de $\SI{5}{\V}$ ;
    \item A l’aide de 2 pinces croco, on relie la carte Arduino (bornes A0 et GND) au GBF ;
    \item Ouvrir le moniteur série et saisir les données demandées selon les valeurs du tableau ci-dessous :
    \end{manip}
    \smallbreak
    \begin{tabularx}{0.7\linewidth}{@{}lYYYYYYY@{}}
        \toprule
        $f_{\mathrm{echantillonnage}} (\si{\hertz}$)  & 100 & 50 & 20 & 10 & 5 & 2 & 1 \\ \midrule
        nombre de bit & \multicolumn{7}{c}{10} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `tcolorbox`:

[image]

Side note: If you use `siunitx` version 3, replace `\SI` with `\qty` and `\si` with `\unit`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\newenvironment{manip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\itemmanip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{myframe}{
    boxrule=1pt,
    colback=white,
    sharp corners, 
    }

\begin{document}
    \section{Spectre électrique}
    \subsection{Numérisation d'un signal}
    
%Text to frame    
    \begin{myframe}
    \paragraph{Manipulation 1 : programme numerisation.ino}
\begin{manip}
    \item \'{A} l’aide d’un oscilloscope, on règle un GBF de manière à obtenir une sinusoïde de fréquence $f = \SI{1}{\hertz}$ tout le temps positive dont la tension crête à crête est de $\SI{4}{\volt}$ sans dépasser une valeur maximale de $\SI{5}{\V}$ ;
    \item A l’aide de 2 pinces croco, on relie la carte Arduino (bornes A0 et GND) au GBF ;
    \item Ouvrir le moniteur série et saisir les données demandées selon les valeurs du tableau ci-dessous :
    \end{manip}
    \smallbreak
    \begin{tabularx}{0.7\linewidth}{@{}lYYYYYYY@{}}
        \toprule
        $f_{\mathrm{echantillonnage}} (\si{\hertz}$)  & 100 & 50 & 20 & 10 & 5 & 2 & 1 \\ \midrule
        nombre de bit & \multicolumn{7}{c}{10} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
 \end{myframe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please use `f_{\mathrm{echantillonnage}}` too painful otherwise:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle why this is too painful otherwise ?

Comment: @Nicolas never use the default math italic font for words, it is designed to separate letters and make them look like a product of single letter variables. use `\mathrm` or if you want italic `\mathit`.  Compare `$diff$` and `$\mathit{diff}$` for an extreme case.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I completely overlooked that and just edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for reminding me.